# adding a property in a class inside d.ts file inside node_modules typescript

Tags: typescript

There is a class called 'Game' inside **phaser.d.ts** file inside **node_modules/phaser**.

I want to add an extra property 'GLOBAL' to the class 'Game' without touching **node_modules**.

how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use whats called augmentation which would look to something along the lines of :

https://codesandbox.io/embed/typescript-playground-export-forked-55dnzo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
// global.d.ts
declare module 'phaser' {
    interface Game {
       GLOBAL: any;
    }
}
```

Hope that will help you

Comment: I get an error.
Duplicate identifier 'Game'.
phaser.d.ts: 'Game was also declared here

Comment: I found the problem and edit the response, you can see the result in the console